# Pandas: if column names are the same, I want to stack them on top of each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as following:

| id | a | b | a | b | c | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 6 | 7 | 3 | 4 | blue |
| 456 | 2 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 5 | yellow |

As you can see, some of the columns have the same. What I want to do is to stack the columns with the same names on top of each other (make the table longer than wider). I have looked into documentations of stack, melt and pivot but I can't find a similar problem as I have here. Can anyone help me how this can be achieved?

FYI, here is how I need the table to be:

| id | a | b | c | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 6 | 4 | blue |
| 123 | 7 | 3 | 4 | blue |
| 456 | 2 | 8 | 5 | yellow |
| 456 | 9 | 7 | 5 | yellow |

Answer (score 1):

You can deduplicate with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) the missing values:

```
(df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns,
                                        df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).cumcount()
                                       ]), axis=1)
   .stack().groupby(level=0).ffill()
   .reset_index(drop=True).convert_dtypes() # optional
   [list(dict.fromkeys(df.columns))] # also optional, keep original order
)
```

output:

```
    id  a  b  c   color
0  123  1  6  4    blue
1  123  7  3  4    blue
2  456  2  8  5  yellow
3  456  9  7  5  yellow
```

Comment: This is very smart! thanks so much! I've been looking for an answer for a while!

Answer (score 0):

```
# melt to turn wide to long format
df2=df.melt(id_vars=['id']) 

(df2.assign(seq=df2.groupby(['variable']).cumcount()) # assign a seq to create multiple rows for an id
 .pivot(index=['id','seq'], columns='variable', values='value' ) # pivot
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns='seq')
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
).ffill()  # fill nan with previous value
```

```
id  a   b   c   color
0   123     1   6   4   blue
1   123     7   3   4   blue
2   456     2   8   5   yellow
3   456     9   7   5   yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); I added a temporary column `c1`, so there is a balance in the number for all columns:

```py
(df
.assign(c1=df.c)
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['id', 'color'], 
    names_to = '.value', 
    names_pattern = '(.)')
)
    id   color  a  b  c
0  123    blue  1  6  4
1  456  yellow  2  8  5
2  123    blue  7  3  4
3  456  yellow  9  7  5
```